# (Vuetify) Menu (open on hover) gives Vue Warn: Property "props" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a menu structured like this:

```
<v-menu :open-on-hover="item.children.length > 0" close-on-content-click="false" v-for="(item, index) in menus" :key="index" :value="index">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
        <v-btn color="rgb(0 0 0 / 65%)" v-bind="props" :prepend-icon="'fa:fas ' + item.iconClass" v-on:click="navigate(item.url)" class="text-capitalize"> {{ item.label }} </v-btn>
      </template>
      <v-list v-if="item.children.length > 0">
        <template v-for="submenu in item.children" :key="'s' + submenu.id">
          <v-divider v-if="submenu.hasHrBefore" :key="'hrb' + submenu.id"></v-divider>
          <v-list-item :prepend-icon="'fa:fas ' + submenu.iconClass" v-on:click="navigate(submenu.url)" :title="submenu.label"></v-list-item>
          <v-divider v-if="submenu.hasHrAfter" :key="'hra' + submenu.id"></v-divider>
        </template>
      </v-list>
    </v-menu>
```

The on hover works well, but Vue continue to give me the following warn (running on Chrome):

```
[Vue warn]: Property "props" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
      at <VListChildren items= [] > 
      at <VList> 
      at <VNavigationDrawer modelValue=false onUpdate:modelValue=fn location="right"  ... > 
      at <TheHeader onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< Proxy(Object) {fetchMenus: ƒ, navigate: ƒ, logout: ƒ, …} > > 
      at <RouterView name="header" > 
      at <VContainer> 
      at <VContainer key=1 > 
      at <App onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< Proxy(Object) {…} > > 
      at <RouterView> 
      at <VApp> 
      at <App>
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Code looks ok, can you turn this into a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com) that shows the error?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not posted the js code...

Try adding the condition logic `item.children.length > 0` into v-if directive as well:

```
<v-menu v-if="item.children" :open-on-hover="item.children.length > 0" close-on-content-click="false" v-for="(item, index) in menus" :key="index" :value="index">
```